# Cast assoc for denormalized database in Elixir Ecto

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have a denormalized database for high performence part of app which consists of 3 schemas:

```
defmodule A do
  schema "a" do
    has_many :b, B
  end

  def changeset(a, attrs) do
    ...
    cast_assoc(a, :b)
  end
end

defmodule B do
  # db columns: b_id
  schema "b" do
    belongs_to :a, A
    has_many :c, C
  end

  def changeset(b, attrs) do
    ...
    cast_assoc(b, :c)
  end
end

defmodule C do
  # db_columns: b_id, a_id
  schema "c" do
    belongs_to :b, B
    belongs_to :a, A # This part is denormalized
  end

  def changeset(c, attrs) do
    ...
  end
end
```

I want to use cast assoc on module A to insert both B and C schemas to database using A.changeset() i get following error

```
  ** (Postgrex.Error) ERROR 23502 (not_null_violation) null value in column "a_id" of relation "c" violates not-null constraint
```

which is understandable (since cast assoc only "passes" b_id to "c" relation.

Is there any way to get that to work without using Ecto.Multi?

Comment: Have you tried `Repo.transaction/2` and insert A and B together, then insert C with the created IDs? https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#c:transaction/2

Comment: I know that approach (similar to ecto multi). Just curious if it's possible to do using built-in ecto cast tooling (without Multi / Repo.transaction)

Comment: No, I don't think this is possible. You will need at least run this inside a function transaction, because you need to know "a_id" when inserting "C". If you didn't have this requirement, then you could insert A, B and C at once.